# Spark: sum over list containing None and Some()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I already understand that I can sum over a list easily using `List.sum`:

```
var mylist = List(1,2,3,4,5)

mylist.sum
// res387: Int = 15
```

**However**, I have a list that contains elements like `None` and `Some(1)`. These values were produced after running a left outer join.

Now, when I try to run `List.sum`, I get an error:

```
var mylist= List(Some(0), None, Some(0), Some(0), Some(1))

mylist.sum
<console>:27: error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Option[Int]]
       mylist.sum
              ^
```

How can I fix this problem? Can I somehow convert the `None` and `Some` values to integers, perhaps right after the left outer join?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `List.collect` method with pattern matching:

```
mylist.collect{ case Some(x) => x }.sum
// res9: Int = 1
```

This ignores the `None` element.

---

Another option is to use `getOrElse` on the `Option` to extract the values, here you can choose what value you want to replace `None` with:

```
mylist.map(_.getOrElse(0)).sum
// res10: Int = 1
```

Answer (score 7):

I find the easiest way to deal with a collection of `Option[A]` is to `flatten` it:

```
val myList = List(Some(0), None, Some(0), Some(0), Some(1))
myList.flatten.sum
```

The call to `flatten` will remove all `None` values and turn the remaining `Some[Int]` into plain old `Int`--ultimately leaving you with a collection of `Int`.

And by the way, embrace that immutability is a first-class citizen in Scala and prefer `val` to `var`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid creating extra intermediate collections with `flatten` or `map` you should consider using an `Iterator`, e.g.

```
mylist.iterator.flatten.sum
```

or

```
mylist.iterator.collect({ case Some(x) => x }).sum
```

or

```
mylist.iterator.map(_.getOrElse(0)).sum
```

I think the first and second approaches are a bit better since they avoid unnecessary additions of 0. I'd probably go with the first approach due to it's simplicity.

If you want to get a bit fancy (or needed the extra generality) you could define your own `Numeric[Option[Int]]` instance. Something like this should work for any type `Option[N]` where type `N` itself has a `Numeric` instance, i.e. `Option[Int]`, `Option[Double]`, `Option[BigInt]`, `Option[Option[Int]]`, etc.

```
implicit def optionNumeric[N](implicit num: Numeric[N]) = {
  new Numeric[Option[N]] {
    def compare(x: Option[N], y: Option[N]) = ??? //left as an exercise :-)
    def fromInt(x: Int) = if (x != 0) Some(num.fromInt(x)) else None
    def minus(x: Option[N], y: Option[N]) = x.map(vx => y.map(num.minus(vx, _)).getOrElse(vx)).orElse(negate(y))
    def negate(x: Option[N]) = x.map(num.negate(_))
    def plus(x: Option[N], y: Option[N]) = x.map(vx => y.map(num.plus(vx, _)).getOrElse(vx)).orElse(y)
    def times(x: Option[N], y: Option[N]) = x.flatMap(vx => y.map(num.times(vx, _)))
    def toDouble(x: Option[N]) = x.map(num.toDouble(_)).getOrElse(0d)
    def toFloat(x: Option[N]) = x.map(num.toFloat(_)).getOrElse(0f)
    def toInt(x: Option[N]) = x.map(num.toInt(_)).getOrElse(0)
    def toLong(x: Option[N]) = x.map(num.toLong(_)).getOrElse(0L)
    override val zero = None
    override val one = Some(num.one)
  }
}
```

Examples:

```
List(Some(3), None, None, Some(5), Some(1), None).sum
//Some(9)

List[Option[Int]](Some(2), Some(4)).product
//Some(8)

List(Some(2), Some(4), None).product
//None

List(Some(Some(3)), Some(None), Some(Some(5)), None, Some(Some(1)), Some(None)).sum
//Some(Some(9))

List[Option[Option[Int]]](Some(Some(2)), Some(Some(4))).product
//Some(Some(8))

List[Option[Option[Int]]](Some(Some(2)), Some(Some(4)), None).product
//None

List[Option[Option[Int]]](Some(Some(2)), Some(Some(4)), Some(None)).product
//Some(None) !?!?!
```

Note that there may be multiple ways of representing "zero", e.g. `None` or `Some(0)` in the case of `Option[Int]`, though preference is given to `None`. Also, note this approach contains the basic idea of how one goes about turning a semigroup (without an additive identity) into a monoid.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a .fold or .reduce and implement the sum of 2 Options manually. But I would go by the [@Psidom approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43462694/4398050)

Answer (score 0):

Folding on the list is a more optimized solution. Beware of chaining function calls on collections, as you may be iterating over something like a `List` multiple times.

A more optimized approach would look something like

```
val foo = List(Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(3))

foo.foldLeft(0)((acc, optNum) => acc + optNum.getOrElse(0))
```